# I am trying to give the heuristics using random function. Can anyone please correct me

Tags: a-star

```
def getNeighbors(v, adjacency_list):
    return adjacency_list[v]

import random

def h(n):
    H = {
            'A': 14,
            'B': 12,
            'C': 11,
            'D': 6,
            'E': 4,
            'F': 11,
            'Z':random.randint(0,22),
```

Error message shows in this line saying invalid syntax.
h('Z')=='Z',
}

```
    return H[n]

def A_star(start_node, stop_node,adjacency_list):
    open_list = set([start_node])
    closed_list = set([])
    g = {}

    g[start_node] = 0
        
    parents = {}
    parents[start_node] = start_node

    while len(open_list) > 0:
        n = None            
        for v in open_list:
            if n == None or g[v] + h(v) < g[n] + h(n):
                n = v;
        if n == None:
            print('Path does not exist!')
            return None
                     
        if n == stop_node:
            reconst_path = []
            while parents[n] != n:
                reconst_path.append(n)
                n = parents[n]

            reconst_path.append(start_node)
            reconst_path.reverse()
            print('Path found: {}'.format(reconst_path))
            return reconst_path
            
        for (m, weight) in getNeighbors(n,adjacency_list):
            if m not in open_list and m not in closed_list:
                open_list.add(m)
                parents[m] = n
                g[m] = g[n] + weight
            else:
                if g[m] > g[n] + weight:
                    g[m] = g[n] + weight
                    parents[m] = n
                    if m in closed_list:
                        closed_list.remove(m)
                        open_list.add(m)

        open_list.remove(n)
        closed_list.add(n)

    print('Path does not exist!')
    return None
adjacency_list = {
     'A': [('B', 4), ('C', 3)],
     'B': [('E', 12),('F',5)],
     'C': [('D', 7),('E',10)],
     'D': [('E',2)],
     'E': [('Z',5)],
     'F': [('Z',16)]
     }

A_star('A', 'Z',adjacency_list)
```

I would like to know if there is anything wrong with my code. Here I am trying to implement the A star algorithm while giving heuristics randomly, Are there any mistakes that I have done. I know there might be a very silly one. If you find anything please correct me.

Comment: @c0der CodeReview is for working code. As the OP states that they get an error message and are asking for help on fixing it, this would not be suitable for CodeReview.